# Responsive email template

Tags: email, html-email, email-templates

I am working on a email template in which I wants to create a `three columns grid structure` for desktop and `single column structure` for mobile devices, I don't want to use the media query because it is not supported in android devices. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anshul,
Media queries are supported on Android as long as you use table stacking and not TD stacking. More on that here: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how_android_is_strangling_responsive_design

Your other option, which will make it work everywhere, is to use fluid-hybrid design: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the hybrid email template. You can view a [demo here](http://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/cerberus-hybrid.html) or get the example [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/master/cerberus-hybrid.html)

[image]

This method uses the [ghost table](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/using-ghost-columns-to-fix-alignment-problems-in-outlook) which fixes the column issue in Outlook desktop.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Answer (score 0):

as others have mentioned you should look into the **hybrid** or **spongy** method of email design that uses min/max-widths instead of media queries to reconfigure the layout.

I wrote and maintain the [Cerberus templates](http://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/); the **Hybrid** one achieves what you asked about.

> This template uses a hybrid approach to reconfigure the layout for
>   different screen sizes for email clients regardless of media query
>   support. At its core, it uses max-width and min-width to impose rigid
>   baselines (allowing some movement) and imposes a fixed, wide width for
>   Outlook who is shackled to desktop anyway. Once a mobile-friendly
>   baseline is set, media queries progressively enhance the email further
>   in clients that support it.

This code is largely built upon [Fabio Carneiro's hybrid code](https://github.com/fcarneiro/tedc15_template). His code contains a (relatively) simple [3 column fluid scaffold](https://github.com/fcarneiro/tedc15_template/blob/master/scaffolds/3_column_scaffold_fluid.html), which you might be helpful.